# Is there a way to assign payment methods to shipping methods in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The shipping company we're working with is giving us different price estimates based on whether the customer wants to pay via wire transfer or via cash on delivery.

So, in simple terms, whenever the customer wants to pay via "cash on delivery" shipping should be more expensive than the "wire transfer" shipping.

The problem is - whenever I specify two flat rates for shipping (one for "cash on delivery" and another for "wire transfer") WooCommerce is still giving me two options to choose from when it comes to payment. It should hide the "wire transfer" payment method whenever I choose the "cash on delivery" shipping flat rate.

Right now when the customer chooses the "cash on delivery" shipping WooCommerce is still giving him an option to select a payment method. It makes no sense presently.

**This is what it looks like:**
[image]

- `Wysyłka` means shipping method, as you can see there are two of these, one is for `cash on delivery`, the other one is for `wire transfer`.
- At the bottom of the form you have `Przelew bankowy` and `Za pobraniem`. Those are payment methods (`COD` and `Wire transfer`). **I want WooCommerce to hide one of those payment methods based on the shipping choice.**

Is it even possible to achieve what I am looking for? I'd be grateful for any help. Thank you.

Comment: If you are searching for plugin solutions, there is a plugins for this: https://woocommerce.com/products/conditional-shipping-and-payments/